# require library returns 'missing file' message

Tags: ruby, dependencies, rubygems, require

I have a small application which I created using jeweler. The jeweler generates a lib/ directory, where I suppose to write my code.

This gem I'm creating depends on the httparty gem, so, in my Rakefile I put

```
  Jeweler::Tasks.new do |gem|
    gem.add_dependency('httparty', '>= 0.4.5')
    ...
  end
```

in my implementation file I put

```
require 'httparty'
```

but when I executes it I get:

> lib/my_app.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- httparty (LoadError)

I have already installed the httparty gem using

```
sudo gem install httparty
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to require rubygems before requiring any gem.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
```

Comment: This cures only the symptom not the illnes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to require rubygems

```
require 'rubygems'
```

before you require httparty

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
require "httparty"
```

ruby is searching in different locations for httparty.rb or httparty.so. Where ruby searches and in which order is stored in the global variable $:

On my debian system it looks like this:

```
$: # =>  ["/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux", "."]
```

But httparty.rb is in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httparty-0.4.5/lib/httparty.rb, so it can not be found. When you do

```
require "rubygems"
```

The Kernel#require method is changed, to find rubygems.

require "rubygems" makes your code platform dependant:

- Somebody might install your library through another method than rubygems
- Some linux distributions (ex. gentoo) make it uneccasary to require "rubygems"

On my debian systems I symlink every rubygems library to /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/, this path is included in the standard search path($:). You can find more about this at http://tomayko.com/writings/require-rubygems-antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

[Some people do not consider it good practise](http://tomayko.com/writings/require-rubygems-antipattern) to require rubygems in distributable code. The solution is to `require rubygems` before loading your own new gem from your application code. (you'll need to do that anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with line:

```
gem "httparty", :git => 'https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty.git'
```

When I turn to:

```
gem "httparty"
```

everything started to work.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you try to make http posts with Ruby, but have not completed setting up Rubygems and RVM.

1. First, check that rubygems and rubygems-update are installed properly using the tutorial here:http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3
2. If you're using RVM, you'll also need to create a gemset and select a ruby version first.

$ rvm gemset list

If this shows you're on (default), then you'll need to configure your RVM.

Find the ruby version you want to use ($ ruby -v) will work and substitute it here:

$ rvm use 1.9.2-head@albinochipmunk --create

1. After your rubygems is installed and your RVM has a selected gemset and ruby version, you'll be able to install httparty without sudo:

$ gem install httparty

Installing httparty with sudo may break RVM configuration, so you want to avoid that. Also, using a new RVM gemset will mean that you may need to reinstall some gems.